# Does the Eastern Orthodox Church acknowledge the validity a self-started Eucharists?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, communion

Let's say on some island in Oceania the locals one day found a King James version (or any other version in their own language) and believed into Christ, started having regular meetings, in which they would pray  and practice Eucharist with bread and wine.

Will the Eastern Orthodox Church acknowledge that kind of Eucharist as valid, that is, a true Eucharist?

Comment: this sounds like a “What if Question”  I think it’s not, I think you are basically asking if a community separate from the EOC can have a valid communion based on scripture rather than the Mystery of Christ’s ministerial Priesthood.  Apostolic succession and so forth.

Comment: @Marc - Yes, that's exactly what I am asking about.

Comment: You might try editing your question to better express this.  For example, instead of saying “Would they” say “do they” and also a general clean up of your intent.   I’d help but final drafts are not my gift.